# Is there a way to confirm the app that generated a key on iOS?

Tags: ios, security, encryption

I am looking to build a simple remote attestation solution for an iOS app. If the secure enclave is used to generate a key, is there metadata that comes with that key that can be used to remotely verify which app (and version) was used to generate the key?

Thanks.

Comment: In a word: no. The best suggestion is not to create your own authentication, it is not easy to get correct. You really need to provide more details on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Similar [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46914154/ios-hardware-backed-key-attestation/47017333#47017333) (just fyi).